# How to mock method called in `created` Vue lifecycle hook in Jest unit test without using deprecated `methods` param in `shallowMount`?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

***NOTE: the linked "duplicate" question & answer does NOT answer my question, please vote to reopen or otherwise explain why this has been closed in comments***

I have a `created()` hook that calls `doSomething()` method. I can get the tests to pass by passing the `methods` param to `shallowMount()` and overiding with `jest.fn()`.

However when I take this approach I receive the deprecation warnings regarding `methods`:

```
console.error
[vue-test-utils]: overwriting methods via the `methods` property is deprecated and will be removed in 
the next major version. There is no clear migration path for the `methods` property - Vue does not 
support arbitrarily replacement of methods, nor should VTU. To stub a complex method extract it from 
the component and test it in isolation. Otherwise, the suggestion is to rethink those tests.
```

TestComponent.Vue:

```
...

created() {
    doSomething();
}

...

methods: {
    doSomething(): void { /* do something */ }
}
```

TestComponent.test.ts:

```
// mounting method used for tests
function genMount() {
    const doSomething = jest.fn();
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(el);

    return shallowMount(TestComponent, {
        localVue,
        methods: { doSomething },  // deprecated param
        store,
        mocks,
        attachTo: el,
        stubs
    });
}
```

How can I mock the method called in the `created()` hook without passing `methods` to `shallowMount()` to resolve the deprecation warnings?

Alternatively, is there a way to either mock or bypass the `created()` lifecycle hook?

Per the warning suggestion, I realize I could import the method and mock it for tests but I am looking for an alternative especially in cases where that would be overkill.

Comment: The linked 'duplicate' does not answer my question. Not sure why this was closed.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I didn't even know this was deprecated. This is the way I have been testing methods called during `mounted` too, so here is what I found. Personally I'll go with the first option going forward.

**If you're willing to change your testing philosophy but not your coding style:**

> I guess the solution is to not test if those methods are called, but if their effects are applied. That's all good, until you deal with the DOM (where Jest/JSDOM in some cases severely lacks functionality).
>
> [Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1536#issuecomment-625303174)

**Else, if you're willing to change your coding style but not your testing philophy:**

> One immediately work around that comes to mind (maybe not ideal) would be to put said method in another file and import it. Then you could use `jest.mock`.
>
> [Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1529#issuecomment-625543974)

Someone else recommended silencing the errors:

```
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils';

config.showDeprecationWarnings = false;
```

...But I think that could cause more problems than it would fix. If not now, then later. Unless your project decides to never update to newer Vue versions I suppose?

These are the only solutions I was able to dig up. I wish I could have found a better answer. It would be nice if we could pause somewhere between `created` and `mounted` and mock a method, but I'm not even sure whether the methods object exists at that point and I don't know how to find out.